# qunit check if event bound to element

Tags: events, qunit

```
/// <reference path="../../../Scripts/myObjectScript.js" />

module("My Test", {
  setup: function () {
      setUpDOM();
  },
  teardown: function () {

  }
});

test("initialize. page load. setPrimaryWarning bound to change event of primary checkbox", function () {
myObject.Initialize(); 
var events = $("#Primary").data('events');
equal(1, events.length);
});

function setUpDOM() {
var $primaryCheckBox = "<input data-val='true' data-val-required='Need Primary' id='Primary' name='Primary' type='checkbox' value='false' data-blur-setup='true'>";
$("#qunit-fixture").append($primaryCheckBox);
```

}

This fails with error **Died on test #1 undefined: Unable to get value of the property 'data': object is null or undefined**

If I test in the dev tools in chrome $("#Primary").data('events'); will return an Object. Any ideas how I see if an event is bound to an element in qunit or what is wrong with the way I've laid my test out above?